# Drupal: help with content type creating & linking nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, content-type

I have a situation where someone can create a job content type. I've added a CCK field that is related to the 'organisation' content type. So when someone creates a new job posting they can choose which organisation the job is for in that field (auto completed). The problem is I can create a new job and select any organisation, even if I didn't create that organisation myself.

Is there a way I can restrict what someone types in that field to 1. an organisation name that exists, and 2. an organisation that belong to that user?

I'm using drupal 6.

Any help most appreciated!

Jonesy

Answer (score 1):

You can use a php rule for the allowed values array of your node reference field, which I think in your case would need to run a quick query for all the nodes made by the current user.

I have not tested this code, but it should be reasonably close to what you're after if I have understood the question!

```
global $user; //make sure we have access to the user

//find all the job organisation nodes made by this user 
//(replace organisation with the actual name of your content type)
$query = db_query("select nid from {node} where type = 'organisation' and uid = %d", $user->uid);

//put the results in the values array
$values = array()
while($result = db_fetch_result($query)){
  $values[] = $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a place where I can check this easily, but you could also try using a select on the edit page, and display the choices with a view.  Then, create a view over the content type and check that the node user is the logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Nodereference field.

It's Autocomplete, and on the bottom of the settings of the field, you can select a View to filter the Nodes that can be referenced ( it's called "Advanced - Nodes that can be referenced (View) ")

Just make a View limiting the nodes to nodes that the current logged in user created, and use that on the Nodereference settings page.
Using that option, drops the option 'Content types that can be referenced' which is located above the Advanced settings.
So make sure to add a filter on node type.

I assume you already use Nodereference, and you might have looked past that option